# Testing appended html attributes with React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that takes a child and uses `React.cloneElement` to append an `id` attribute to the rendered HTML. This works in a browser setting, however, doesn't appear to during a test. Using RTL's `debug` function, I can see that the tree that gets rendered by jest never includes the appended attribute. Here's the gist of what I currently have:

```
// map over the children, set the new component tree as state 
const id = "test-cloak"
setTree(React.cloneElement(child, { id, test: "hello" }));

// the component tree now returns the following when logged:
     {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
      type: [Function: BasicComponentTree],
      key: '.0',
      ref: null,
      props: { id: 'test-cloak', test: 'hello' },
      _owner: null,
      _store: {}
    }

// when the component is returned, render the new tree conditionally
{tree && <Fragment key={id}>{tree}</Fragment>}
```

The easy option here is to wrap the tree in an element with an ID, but this doesn't fulfil what I need it to do - the component should change the passed in children in a way that won't affect any layout. Wrapping an element would potentially mean breaking some css elsewhere.

When I run the test, here's what I get:

```
   <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-testid="cloak-test"
        >
          <style>

          @media(max-width: 800px) {
            #test-cloak {
              display: none;
            }
          }

          </style>
          // This should have the appended id attribute
          <div>
            <h1>
              Cloak me!
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

How can I go about testing the rendered html after React has passed through the props as attributes? I want to avoid testing the state of the `tree`, what I really care about is that the attribute reaches the DOM